# using make command

Tags: make

I'm following the author's instructions on getting started with c++20 for lazy programmers.The instructions were go into external/SSDL/unix then type make. I did that but got error  message. here is what i saw in the terminal.

```
/Desktop/lazy/cpp20/external/SSDL/unix$ make
make -C bin/shared
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/michael/Desktop/lazy/cpp20/external/SSDL/unix/bin/shared'
g++ -c -fPIC `sdl2-config --cflags` -I../../../include  ../../../src/SSDL_color.cpp -o SSDL_color.o
/bin/sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
In file included from ../../../src/SSDL_color.cpp:23:
../../../include/SSDL_color.h:26:10: fatal error: SDL.h: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "SDL.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:37: SSDL_color.o] Error 1
```

how do I correct this? thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be missing the [header files](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/header-files/) for SDL. In Ubuntu, header files can be typically found in packages that have `dev` in their name. My first guess would be to try the package [libsdl2-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libsdl2-dev), but you may want to double check that.

Comment: does this mean that i should add libsdl2-dwv to sdl

Comment: @BobBarrett It means you need to use `apt` to install the package containing the header files. As I said, I would assume that to be `libsdl2-dev`, but I'm not completely sure about that.